# Restore from fullscreen using Esc button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to restore my full screen using Esc button. Its restoring correctly using space bar but  with Esc it don't restore the view state correctly.

I am using view state while going to full screen and while restoring it will come back to default state.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the KeyboardEvent. Add event listner on KEY_UP or KEY_DOWN. And then check for the keycode in the eventhandler function. If ESC key is pressed then restore the window. Please see the below mentioned code, it might be helpful

```
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,reportKeyUp);

function reportKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
         this.stage.nativeWindow.restore();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. i tried your code,Esc in full screen is breaking my page and then on pressing again its restoring properly. I think click of Esc is not changing the view state properly. If you have any other suggestion, pls let me know.